# After changing Google Analytics Custom Dimensions from user id to user name, some ids are still showing up in reports

Tags: google, google-analytics, wordpress, analytics, custom-dimensions

I have a WordPress website and I setup a custom dimension in Google Analytics to log, as a custom dimension, the blog post authors user ID. This worked fine.

I have since changed this to now log the username instead of the ID and this is also working fine and showing in the reports.

Hovever, although it now logs the username, I'm still getting logs in the reports which are using the ID instead of the username. Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably a caching issue - old code will be run for a time during the switch over. In my experience, after changing how a custom dimension is used you can get the wrong variables being sent up to 3 months later.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Are you referring to cache at Google Analytics end, cache of the website or cache within the users web browser?

Comment: Client cache - so that covers crawlers as well as browsers. The clients could be running older code for a while, more stubborn ones may ignore server directives to do otherwise. Although modern browsers should respond to an update in e-tag headers

Comment: What is the scope of the custom dimension? Go through - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828#scope for a better understanding of scope